# How to return key comparisons from an open address hash table?

Tags: c, algorithm, hashtable

Below is my code for the hash table. The problem I'm getting is returning the correct number of key comparisons when deleting a key, and sometimes for inserting a key as well. For example, for one test case, the program was supposed to return 2 key comparisons but it only returns 1.

```
int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
  int i = 1;
  int keyComparisons = 0;
  int index = 0;
  HashSlot *newNode;
  
  index = hash1(key);

  if (hashTable[index].key == key) 
    return -1;

  if (hashTable[index].indicator == EMPTY) {
    newNode = (HashSlot *)malloc(sizeof(HashSlot));
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->indicator = USED;
    hashTable[index] = *newNode;
    return 0;
  }  
  else {
    if (hashTable[index].indicator == USED) {
      keyComparisons++;
      index = hash1(key + hash2(key));
    }
    if (hashTable[index].key == key) 
      return -1;
    hashTable[index].key = key;
    hashTable[index].indicator = USED;
    return keyComparisons;
  }
}

int HashDelete(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
  int index = hash1(key);
  int keyComparisons = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (hashTable[index].key != key) {
    index++;
    if (index == TABLESIZE)
      return -1;
      break;
  }

  while (hashTable[index].key != key) {
    keyComparisons+=1;
    index = hash1(key + i*hash2(key));
    i++;
  }

  if (hashTable[index].indicator == DELETED) 
      return -1;

  hashTable[index].indicator = DELETED;
  return keyComparisons;
}
```

Comment: In `HashDelete` why do you have two loops that both look for the key but in a different way. That is, two of these loops: `while (hashTable[index].key != key)`. The second loop will never run because the first loop guarantees the condition is always false when it gets to the second loop.

Comment: Actually my previous comment is not quite true. There is an unconditional `break` in the first loop. The indentation is wrong - the `break` belongs to the `while` block and not the `if` block. Not sure whether you intended that to be there but it means that first loop only ever runs one iterations - which begs the question of why have a loop at all. It seems your code is quite confused in that area. This is also probably the reason why the comparison count is off as the first loop does one comparison but doesn't increment the count.

Comment: Oh actually I wanted to check if the key doesn't exist in the hashtable. Because if it doesn't then it should return -1 as there is no key to delete. Is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: You don't need the first loop at all. The point of a hash table is that you can jump straight to the bucket with a possible key match. You don't need to search for the key through the whole table as that defeats the purpose of using a hash. Why bother hashing if you are going to search the whole table?

Comment: You're right. Can you please show me how to search for the key then and return -1 if not found?

Comment: You haven't described the hashing algorithm so I can't really tell you how to determine when the key is not found. It depends on exactly what the hash collision algorithm is. It looks like you just rehash once if a collision occurs but I don't know whether that is indeed what your assignment specifies.

Comment: Oh ok. So basically yeah I'm using double hashing so once a collision is detected the hash2 algorithm is applied.

Comment: Then you don't need any loops at all. One `if` to check whether the key matches with hash1. If not then another `if` to check if it matches with `hash2`. If still not then `return -1`.

Comment: I tried everything, I'm still getting the wrong answer. The hashing algorithm is (k + i*D(k)) mod h where h is the table size, k is the key, i is some index from 0 to h-1 and D(k) is hash2 on the key. Could you please help with this?